# Timeout while Loop If No Input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a piece of code that does exactly what I need, barring one thing, a timeout.

Basically, this code will log an entry every 0,5s for 3 seconds and then print "Done" and then restart. The sound I am trying to log is constant for about 3,1s, so that's perfect. Every time the sound is present it will print "Done."

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
pin = 7 #Defining pin 7 as Input pin
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN)

list = ["Start"]

while l:
    if GPIO.input(pin) == GPIO.LOW: #This is the input
        if len(list) <= 6:
            list.insert(0, "Entry") #Insert into list at first position
            sleep(0.5) #If there is a constant sound, this makes sure a new item is interted only every 0,5s.
            print ("Not Done")
            print (len(list))

        elif len(list) > 6:
            list = ["Start"]
            print ("Done")
```

So now, I want the code to restart if say it detects a sound and logs it, but then nothing happens for 1 or 2 seconds.

So if the list gets to maybe 3 or 4 units long, but then nothing happens for a second or two, it must go back to being one unit long.

I hope this makes sense. And I hope you can all help me.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You want a long sound to be one signal. You want no sound to be no signal, and a short sound to be no signal.

```
sound_present_for_samples = 0
logging_threshold = 6  # 6 half seconds
while True:
    if GPIO.input(pin) == GPIO.LOW:
        sound_present_for_samples += 1
        if sound_present_for_samples == threshold:
            print("Done")
        elif sound_present_for_samples < threshold:
            print("Not done")
        sleep(0.5)
    else:
        sound_present_for_samples = 0
```

You don't really need a list here. The number in `sound_present_for_samples` is the number of "Entry" you would have in a normal list. You can construct it at any time. `["Entry"]*sound_present_for_samples` with ["Start"] added to front.

If you need real data in the list instead of a string, you can also replace `sound_present_for_samples` with a list, and every +=1 with .append and =0 with =[] and the conditions with len(spfs).

Comment: Thanks @Chad Miller. - It only seems to be working to print "Not Done" - I can't seem to get it to print "Done". When I ran the code for the first time it told me that "threshold" was not defined. So I had to change the "logging_threshold" to just "threshold" for it to work. Do you have any suggestions? Is there a module I'm not importing?

Comment: @LukeVenter, it's just that your logic is wrong. Step through it by hand. Don't run it. Make sure you understand, with pen and paper, what is going on. Draw a box with variable names. Use a coin or dice to decide what GPIO.input(pin) returns. Write the history, Make sure it's doing what you expect.